# Embed flash content/Video In flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to embed "application/x-shockwave-flash" content in my mxml.Basically I want to hit one url , get "application/x-shockwave-flash" content from it and display it in my mxml/swf.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You should load it using the [Spark VideoPlayer and VideoDisplay controls](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc78f87379113c38b-669905c51221a3b97af-8000.html) component for instance.

Comment: Hi thanx for the reply, basically i want to a substitute for        <object width=300 height=300>
    <param name=movie value="some url"></param>
    <param name=wmode value=transparent></param>
    <param name=allowFullScreen value=true></param>
    <param name=allowscriptaccess value=always></param>
    <embed src="some url" type=application/x-shockwave-flash allowscriptaccess=always allowfullscreen=true wmode=transparent width=800 height=800>
    </embed>
</object>  How can i do this?

Comment: But there es no real substitute. If you want to show the video in your Flex application, you have to use MXML and ActionScript.

Comment: yes thats true, but which component exactly? I am using swfloader but it is not giving me the proper result. Is there any way to provide url and url paremeters to swfloader? can u share the code snippet please? that will be very helpful.

Comment: I added a link to my original answer. That should clarify everything with code examples. Please mark as answered if the official documentation works for you.

Comment: If you can take this link for reference "http://widget.startv.in/video/Lr9OzFJu7VqFOz8/LU5gpbEn5U1dk" it returns one swf that plays one video i want to show it as it is in my flex. I dnt wanna use html tag for it.But when i use swfloader i only get outside window and not actual video to be played. The documentation u have shared has some default videoplayer i dont wanna use that, I want the look and feel same as that of shown in that link.